# INotifycollectionchanged on ICollection<T> object

Tags: c#, system.reactive, observer-pattern, inotifycollectionchanged

I want to observe changes in Icollection object given that I can't changed type of the object to observablecollection.How can it be achieved?

```
mycollectionobserver = Observable.FromEventPattern<NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs>  (source.IcollectionItems, "CollectionChanged").Subscribe(OnItemsChanged);
```

Comment: I did it using typecasting: mycollectionobserver = Observable.FromEventPattern<NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs>  (source.IcollectionItems  **as INotifyCollectionChanged**, "CollectionChanged").Subscribe(OnItemsChanged);

Comment: `ICollection<T>` does not implement `INotifyCollectionChanged` so as soon as you cast it using `as` you get `null`. Peter's answer is quite correct - you need to implement a wrapper class, but since you can't change the type then you're out of luck.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What code is actually modifying the collection? Are you able to pass your own object reference to that code instead of the reference to the original `ICollection<T>` object?

If the answer to that second question is "no", then you are out of luck. But if you *can* replace the object reference with your own, then you can implement a wrapper around the `ICollection<T>` object that itself implements `INotifyCollectionChanged`. In that way, your own object would be able to see every modification to the collection and raise the appropriate `INotifyCollectionChanged` events.

If you cannot do that, then the code modifying the collection has no way to use your custom implementation, and will always be able to modify the collection without your own code having a way to know about it.

Finally, note that someone may already have written such a wrapper. I didn't find anything with a quick Google search, but I didn't try very hard. I wouldn't be surprised if one does exist.